# Como interligar prolog com c#

Tags: c#, java, prolog

Queria saber como criar um base de conhecimento em `prolog` e usa-lo numa `interface` criada no `c#` ou `java`, criar novas clausulas via interface.

Comment: Já viu isso? http://www.swi-prolog.org/contrib/CSharp.txt

Comment: Pro caso do Java, há uma integração SWI-Prolog/Java chamada JPL, mas também há a opção de se usar interpretadores Prolog escritos em Java - e portanto no formato bytecode (i.e. portáveis entre plataformas). Um deles é o [GNU Prolog for Java](http://www.gnu.org/software/gnuprologjava/).